# Finding Element in a Linked List of Type Structure (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, data-structures, linked-list, find

I have declared a structure:

```
Public Structure MyStructure
    Public name As String
    Public dataType As String
    Public address As String
End Structure
```

Then a Linked List:

```
Private MyList As New LinkedList(Of MyStructure)
```

What's the best way to find an element in the list given the value of an element in the struct. For example if I want to find the instance of MyStruct where the field name is "readings" in the list, how should I do it? Is there a way to avoid looping through the linked list elements?

Comment: There's a field named 'name', if that field has the value "readings", how should I look for the struct element that has name="readings"?... I used 'name' because in this case is the one field that will be unique for each instance of the structure in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably be better off using a class instead of a Structure:

```
Public Class MyFoo
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property dataType As String
    Public Property address As String
End Class
```

This allows the following:

```
Dim lst As New LinkedList(Of MyFoo)

lst.AddFirst(New MyFoo With {.name = "Ziggy", .address = "here", .dataType = "foo"})
lst.AddFirst(New MyFoo With {.name = "Zoey", .address = "there", .dataType = "bar"})
lst.AddFirst(New MyFoo With {.name = "Curly", .address = "nowhere", .dataType = "any"})

Dim item = lst.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.name = "Ziggy")
If item IsNot Nothing Then
    ' do something
End If
```

There really isnt a way to avoid looping - something somewhere has to iterate the collection to find "Ziggy" (or "readings"); here, *we* just don't have to write code for it.

`FirstOrDefault` will return `Nothing` if the item cannot be found.  Since a Structure is a value type, it cannot ever be `Nothing` (though it can *contain* `Nothing`).  As a result, the line `If item IsNot Nothing` results in a syntax error.

I suppose with a Structure, you could use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` to test if the name is filled in, but I would just use a class.

Comment: Thanks Plutonix, that was helpful. I'll give it a try to classes instead of structures.